# Misinterpretation of Diagram

Tags: geometry, contest-math, analytic-geometry

Let $O=(0,0)$, $A= (0,a)$ and $B= (b,0)$, where $0<a<b$ are reals. Let $\Gamma$ be a circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$ and let $P$ be any other point on $\Gamma$. Line $PA$ meets the $x$-axis again at $Q$. Prove that $\angle BQP = \angle BOP$.

Here is my interpretation of the diagram

[image: diag]

Is it incorrect to assume that $\Gamma$ is the circumcircle of $\triangle AOB$? Can anyone tell me what's the error?

Comment: There is some confusion here.... what is $C$?  Anyway the circle does not passes, in general, from the origin.

Comment: Sorry. It's $AOB$. How is it possible that the circle doesn't pass through the origin?

Comment: You are right! the circle passes through the origin.